# Mail.app message selection gets reset when clearing the search box

Tags: mail.app

If I search for something in my mailbox, select the message I'm interested in, then clear the search box (because I want to see the other messages that came in around the same time), the selection resets and I lose my selected message.

I thought there was once some option like "View message in mailbox" that could be used to select a given message without filtering out everything else, but I can't find it anywhere.

Am I imagining things?  Does this still exist?

-- Edit --

Trying to clarify with screencaps.

1. I search for and select a message.

[image: Imgur]

2. I clear the search.

[image: Imgur]

- The message I had selected has been deselected
- The message list pane has scrolled back to the top

What I want is for the message I had selected to still be selected, or at least visible on the screen.

Comment: Are you sure you loose them? if you do the same search again are they there or not ?

Comment: No, it's still there if I search again.  The problem is that I can't see it "in context" -- I want to see the mailbox the message is in, with the message selected.  But when I clear the search box, it deselects the message.  If it's in a mailbox with thousands of messages (which is generally why I'm searching in the first place) I have to manually browse through the mailbox trying to find it.

Comment: ok let me try that on my mail

Comment: sorry your request does not makes sense to me--deleted my answer

Answer (score 1):

Answering (sort of) my own question.  When making the screenshots I added to the question, I happened to turn off the "Organize by Conversation" option, and it suddenly worked!  When clearing the search box, the selected message remains selected.

Moreover, this also happens:

1. Turn on "Organize by Conversation"
2. Enter some search term
3. Select a message
4. Clear the search box -- the message will be deselected
5. Turn off "Organize by Conversation"
6. The previously selected message is **reselected**

So I guess the "answer" is that "Organize by Conversation" is simply a shoddy feature that Apple bolted onto their mail client without caring too much how well it works.